# FFMPEG record http video stream with normal speed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm recording an http stream from my IP Camera (TPLINK NC200), using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://admin:YWRtaW4=@192.168.0.18:8080/stream/getvideo -t 30 -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.mp4
```

As you can see , the video length is set to 30 seconds ( -t option ) . But it takes about 1 minute 30 seconds to record , and the video speed is very high ( the camera recording a stopwatch and a 30-second video recorded the timer to 1 minute and 11 seconds ).

Is there some ffmpeg option to get a normal speed video? Or the problem is the camera configuration?

Comment: If the camera is not sending a constant framerate stream then this may happen. Try `ffmpeg -t 30 -i http://admin:YWRtaW4=@192.168.0.18:8080/stream/getvideo -vsync 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.mp4`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the video is still very fast. I also tried with the -vsync "1,2,-1 and drop" and it didn't worked too.

Comment: What is the original format of the video stream? mp4? raw h264 stream?

Comment: I used the ffprobe command and get this:

Comment: 'Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc'

Answer (score 1):

Despite the declared 25 fps is your stream likely varying in framerate. I would try this

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i "http://admin:YWRtaW4=@192.168.0.18:8080/stream/getvideo" -t 30 -c copy -y output.mp4
```

Sometimes I get a bunch of *Non-monotonous DTS in output stream* warnings. There seems to be some timebase issue of the input format, and the only help for me is to force mjpeg format instead of mpjpeg.

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f mjpeg -i "http://admin:YWRtaW4=@192.168.0.18:8080/stream/getvideo" -t 30 -c copy -y output.mp4
```